# Where does the text at the top of each search result come from?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search

I'm referring to the `Merriam-Webster` text, it is nowhere on the page HTML, is it from the domain name?

[image: google result]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google determines the *site name* algorithmically, the info doesn't come from any one place. Here are some things you can do to help hint your site name to Google:

> - Use schema.org vocabulary in JSON-LD, RDFa, or microdata format
> - Publish markup on your official website homepage
> - Do not block pages with markup using the Robots Exclusion Protocol
> - Include a WebSite item in your markup using the relevant properties:
>
>   - url = the URL of your official website (required)
>   - name = the preferred name of your website (required)
>   - alternateName = an alternate name you want Google to consider (optional)
>
> Source: [Google’s Mobile Search Results Soon to Show Site Name](https://www.infront.com/blog/mobile-search-site-name/)